# Hide page title in Drupal 7 if a particular block is present

Tags: templates, drupal, view, drupal-blocks

I have a Views 3 block on certain nodes that, amongst other things, renders the node title in the block.

Hence, I need to somehow not render the standard node title if this block exists on a node to avoid duplication. 
Anyone know how I would achieve this? Presume it needs to go into preprocess or the page.tpl?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to Write a PHP code in either header or footer of the view and call this api

```
drupal_set_title ('');
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in the views interface.  Go to:  structure/views/view/view_name/edit

Under Format, select Show fields then select the fields that you would like to display. In the above example, I've selected both the title and the post date.

Alternatively, you can adjust the content type's teaser, default or custom displays and select those display types within the views interface  "Show:Teaser"e.g.  Just go to structure/types/manage/content_type_name/display and fine tune the display that you would like to see.

Personally, I prefer to display specific fields via views.